# Method for demonstrating iPad application in online meetings

Tags: ipad, webinar

We have recently developed an iPad application and now need to start demonstrating it to customers and prospects as part of our overall product suite during webinars. As part of our Agile methodology, we also need to periodically review the application with key customers without having to distribute it since the application is not a standalone application and requires a connection to web services installed at each customer site.

We have searched high and low for any solution that doesn't involve rooting the device but have been unable to find one. The most common suggestion seems to be to point a webcam at the device, but that comes across as very unprofessional.

I know that there are VGA out adapters that can be plugged into the iPad and we have used these to present through a projector when the customer is physically present, but this is a relatively rare occurrence. Perhaps there are solutions that we are unaware of that can be used to send VGA output back into a desktop device for screen sharing?

Comment: Demo from the Simulator and share your screen with Cisco WebEx (or other screen sharing software).

Comment: That is a great suggestion, but I forgot to mention that is the mechanism that we are currently using. The problem is this requires a developer's machine or installation of all source code and dev tools on a marketing machine. We are currently losing a lot of developer time to demos, which is not the highest and best use of their time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a [Slingbox](http://www.slingbox.com/) on your LAN and connect the iPad video to the Slingbox video input.  Then use a web browser on your computer to view the Slingbox feed and share your screen with WebEx as usual.

**EDIT** - BTW, there are other gadgets besides the Slingbox to get composite video into a computer such as [Elgato Video Capture](http://store.apple.com/us/product/TW129LL/A) to name one.

Comment: That is outstanding info, I'd upvote 20 times if I could. One additional note for anyone that runs across this; make sure that you check the connections available on the slingbox (they are displayed on the website) and make sure that you obtain the appropriate iPad adapter (you will most likely need a 30-pin (iPad) to Composite Video adapter, which are easy to find).

Answer (score 1):

A better option would be to use http://www.reflectionapp.com/ 
(Im not affiliated with the company).

Answer (score 1):

I use this app.
http://www.airserverapp.com
It can be used with Windows or Mac.
Easy to use -- the only trouble I have is I keep poking my PC instead of the iPad.